# Create VHD locally and restore in Azure Cloud Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine, vhd

I downloaded and ran sysinternals tools Disk2vhd  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415

I Created a .vhd of my C: drive and I want to push it to the Azure Cloud

The confusing thing is that I start reading about using PowerShell and Prepping the virtual machine

```
Install-Module AzureRM.Compute -RequiredVersion 2.6.0
```

Well that is fine, but that I need about `Sysprep` and I'm confused about where to even run this?    Am I supposed to first create an empty IaaS VM image in the cloud and then RDP into it and do Sysprep on that new VM in Azure?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/upload-generalized-managed

When I read this I start to realize that I'm not suppose to do this on my local machine.

> When Sysprep completes, it shuts down the virtual machine. Do not restart the VM.

Any good resources ?

Comment: I think it should go to server vault

Comment: @RanadipDutta  Oh - where is that , I will look

Comment: Do you want to use your image to create multiple VMs?

Comment: No,  We want to move all our servers  web and sql to azure ,  so I was trying to get started with my own hard drive,  then  make a VHD of a Web Server etc..

Comment: You need use Hyper-V to create a VM with your VHD, then you could execute `Sysprep`.

Comment: Any Specific Video or Article to get me started @Walter-MSFT

Comment: I will give you it as an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139548/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-john-baxter).

Comment: Are you running Windows Server? You're not allowed to run Windows 10 client in Azure.

Comment: `Not allowed`  =  it will detect and not start   OR  that is against licensing?       I have zero intentions to using a windows 10 machine to do anything with.... It was simply the fastest and easiest quick test to get me rolling into understanding how to use a on-prem VHD put it into hyper-v , follow instruction with storage and container and put with powershell .   While that is pushed earlier today , I was creating a Windows 2003 server vhd and a 2012 server vhd so that I can now push though and create a VM from those.   I have not had a chance to see if the other windows 10 was successful

Comment: Getting  `the vhd has an unsupported virtual size the size must be a whole number (in mbs)`    Whether that is from it being a Windows 10 ...  I assume nothing...   That is an awful error message .     SMH

Comment: @RobinShahan-MSFT  -  Ok  different issue with a Server vhd    thx in advance    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163127/loading-vhd-from-disk2vhd-creation-into-a-new-vm-in-hyper-v-showing-flashing-cur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need use Hyper-V to create a VM by with your VHD. More information about using a VHD with Microsoft Hyper-V(Locally) please refer to this [link](http://reflect.macrium.com//help/v5/How_to/ImgToVHD/Using_a_VHD_with_Microsoft_Hyper-V_or_Virtual_PC.htm).

Secondly, you could RDP to your VM and execute `Sysprep` and stop the VM.

Thirdly, you could upload the new VHD to Azure storage account.

Comment: Hey,  so I'm getting an error on Azure when I try to create an image from the uploaded vhd     `the vhd has an unsupported virtual size the size must be a whole number (in mbs)`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not at office. I will try to help you Monday.According the error, it seems your VHD is   not right type, you could search on google or ask new question.

Comment: I figured since it was Windows 10 and it was probably over the size limit, I would move on with what I really need to do , clone this windows 2013 web server  ... Here is my question  (flashing cursor on start of new hyper-v vm with the vhd of that server )    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163127/loading-vhd-from-disk2vhd-creation-into-a-new-vm-in-hyper-v-showing-flashing-cur